# What is the benefit of encoding fullstops before storing them in the tags table?

Tags: discussion, tags

I read that fullstops are encoded as `aspûnet` on [SQLServerPEdia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema):

> StackOverflow limits you to five tags per question (answers aren't tagged), and all five are stored in this field. For example, for question 305223, the Tags field is "<offtopic><fun><not-programming-related><jon-skeet>" [...]  StackOverflow allows periods in the tag, like the .NET tag and ASP.NET tag. However, in the database, these are stored as "aspûnet". Just something to be aware of.

So:

- What functional benefits does encoding fullstops as `aspûnet` yield?
- Also, what functional benefits does surrounding a tag with `<>` yield?

Comment: Hmmm, wondering if the `û` is not some encoding problem with that very website? It also has an issue with space in "Stack Overflow". ;-)

Comment: Perhaps this question should be migrated to SO? It's really a programming question that the subject matter of which is related to SO; but it can be for any other app.

Comment: (@Mel, there's no migration path from MSO to other sites.)

Comment: @Arjan: a '.' is encoded the same way in virtually all encodings in the world, so no.

Comment: @Kop, I was thinking about the dot being replaced by some other character or sequence, that somehow erroneously displayed as `û` on the site. Like [a Unicode `û`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb) is `0xC3BB` in UTF-8. Hence, if the dot *would* have been encoded as 8-bit ASCII `Ã»` then erroneously *assuming* UTF-8 would get one to see the `û`. Of course, encoding the dot as 8-bit ASCII `Ã»` makes no sense at all, but there's many other options, especially when there's multiple erroneous encodings/decodings. Anyway, the dot does not seem to be encoded at all. Or: not anymore?

Comment: (In 8-bit ASCII, `û` is `0xFB`, or `11111011`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the encoding of the dot [is used (anymore)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16980/show-me-the-tags):

```
select Tags
from Posts
where Id = 3397235;​

tags                
------------------- 
<c#><.net><asp.net>
```

And using `<...>` seems just some random way to ensure one can keep the tags apart using some characters that will not appear in any tag itself? Just guessing though. Also, using a separator rather than both some prefix *and* suffix, makes queries such as `where Tags like '%<.net>%'` a bit harder. But then I don't know if such ill-performing queries would be used.

Comment: Would it not make sense to use a coma delimited list to separate the tags?

Comment: I guess one might not have expected a dot or hash in the tags either, when designing the database. Hence: can one be sure the comma is never used in a future tag? (Just guessing.)

Comment: Also, a delimiter is harder in `like` queries. See my edit, @Mel.

Comment: I believe the tags field is full-text indexed.